# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextTab

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Recently, I've been receiving this error in the debugger.

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextTab
```

This works fine on iOS 7, but not on iOS 6. I've done some research and I realize that the error comes from missing APIs which are available in iOS 7, but not in iOS 6. But my question is how in the world do I debug this.

*I never reference NSTextTab in any of my classes.*

My app crashes immediately after launch on iOS 6.

Is there a breakpoint I can use to find out where this error is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: please paste your code here. yes you can tap on left side on the your code panel (when line no is showing.) for break points.

Comment: enable breakpoints by switching to the breakpoint navigator, then in the bottom click the "+" button, run your app again and tell which code and where does your app crashes

Comment: @Malloc I have breakpoints running, but the breakpoints converge onto a line on the assembler, which is useless.

Comment: I don't see how using NSZombies are suppose to help, but I used it anyway, and there is no memory leak whatsoever.

Comment: Do you use `NSParagraphStyle` class ? Check your text handling code, your problem is related to it.

Comment: Oh gosh one of the controls I'm using is... Trying to fix now. Hopefully disabling this will fix the problem. +1

Comment: @Emmanuel If you want to post this as an answer ill be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think it's will better that you post the correct answer, with the line of code that cause the problem. My comment being just an indication, to help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Emmanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717391/emmanuel), I have figured out the answer to the problem.

According to the documentation, [NSTextTab](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextTab_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html) is declared under the class which I was using [NSMutableParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Since [NSTextTab](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextTab_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html) is available in only iOS 7 and later, the crash comes from unknown API calls in the iOS 6 SDK.

My application uses the control from Cocoanetics, "[DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)," which apparently no longer supports iOS 6. In order to fix this problem, I reverted the control to a older version which did support iOS 6 using:

```
 pod 'DTCoreText', '1.5.3'
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future while using this class with backward compatibility to iOS 6 from iOS 7.

Comment: @jackslash Theres a 2 day delay before I can accept my own answer.